# In Bulletstorm, whats the best weapon to get rid of burnouts, FAST!

Tags: bulletstorm

I'm playing Bulletstorm for the second time through. I played on either normal or easy the first time. I'm now playing on very hard and was doing okay (except the train part took a few tries). I'm getting to the burnouts, and I can defeat the first couple waves. However, once I slide into the room under the broken door, I can only defeat the first few before I get OWNED!!

I was wondering if any of you guys have played on very hard and what your best strategy/weapon against these giant glowing pieces of sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I jumped like a maniac and used the flail and machine gun. It is important to aim for the glowing sores on their bodies to hurt them if you do not only want to slow them down with the flail gun.

I am not sure, but are there no explosives in that area which you could trigger?

Comment: Greetings from 7 years later. How are you jumping? As far as I know there is no jumping in this game.

Comment: It could be possible that you are right. I don't remember much. It could be possible that I only run around like a maniac.

Answer (score 1):

The Boneduster is particularly useful because its knockback effect works despite the Burnouts' resistance to bullets.

Burnout encounters usually occur near environmental hazards, such as wall spikes or cacti. Manoeuvre Burnouts in front of these then blast them or kick them for a one-shot kill.